# Ubuntu command line system with LXDE

Tags: 10.04, command-line, lxde

When installing a standard Ubuntu 10.04 system on my system, I have to use `i915.modeset=0 xforcevesa` when beginning the installation.  I tried doing the same for a command line installation so I could have a base system and install lxde later, it doesn't work, i.e. if I don't use `i915.modeset=0 xforcevesa`, after booting, it just shows a blank screen.  I get the same with a command line system plus lxde, i.e. a blank screen.

So my question is, where do I have to enter `i915.modeset=0 xforcevesa` after installing a command line install plus lxde?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing a minimal install, you will need to install the X packages yourself prior to installing the desktop of your choice.

Thus, the key packages are `xorg, xserver-xorg-core` together with the video driver of your choice.

If you are just testing, my suggestion would be to install `xserver-xorg-input-all` for all the possible input devices together with `xserver-xorg-video-all` for all the open-source video-drivers.

Install these packages first, together with the GRUB entries `quiet i915.modeset=0 xforcevesa` to allow the GUI to display correctly.

Comment: I would prefer to install only install the required stuff only.  How would I figure out which input device I need and which video driver I need?

Comment: ... try installing all the stuff first to confirm that it is a driver issue first.  If you install both input-all and video-all together with i915.modeset=0 and xforcevesa and you still get a black screen then we are looking for another solution.

Comment: Done, and I have discovered that `i915.modeset=1` is what I need, `i915.modeset=0` gives a blank screen and `xforcevesa` also works, but without any desktop effects.  Tested this using the standard ubuntu live cd.  After which I installed a base install and edited the grub file by adding `i915.modeset=1` and i can get into slim and lxde.  I will start a new question about the input-all and video-all.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: ok - its definitely the intel driver (`xserver-xorg-video-intel`) you need to install together with xorg and xserver-xorg-core.  All the possible xserver-xorg-video stuff you could individually install is linked here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=names&keywords=xserver-xorg-video

Answer (score 1):

Using any editor, open `/etc/default/grub`

```
# Graphical 
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub

# Command line
sudo -e /etc/default/grub
```

In your case, you may need to boot to recovery mode.

Look for the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash”
```

and add in those options

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet i915.modeset=0 xforcevesa console=tty1”
```

I personally would remove the splash, up to you.

Then update grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

I think you are affected by this bug : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/914311

Comment: I'm still getting a blank screen.

Comment: Have you looked at something like: http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2010/05/06/ubuntu-10-04-lucid-blank-screen-at-startup-workaround/ ?

Comment: I updated my answer, try adding `console=tty1` as well, see the bug report I referenced.